# Creating a method that takes in a List in C#

Tags: c#, list, methods

Hi I am trying to create the following method in C#
Create a method last3YearInInches. It should take in an ArrayList (Java) or List
(C#) of Doubles.

■ If the size of the list is less than 3, return 100

■ Otherwise take the LAST 3 items in the list and average them together.

■ Return the average

This is what I have to far but I am getting errors when trying to use only the last three of the list.

```
public double last3YearsInInches(List<Double> list )
        {   

            if(list.Count < 3)
            {
                return 100;
            }
            else
            {
               double lastThree= list.Reverse<Double>().Take(3);
                double average = lastThree / 3;
                return average; 
            }
        }
```

Comment: `double lastThree= list.Reverse<Double>().Take(3).Average();`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko and they just learned nothing.  You should have pointed out what the error was and allowed them to then attempt to fix.  This was clearly homework and they still have no clue why it was wrong.

Comment: What error did you see, and where in the code did it happen? Also provide some sample inputs for checking.

Comment: yup. but otoh, he ignored the error messages, too..

Comment: It is underlined red and says cannot explicitly convert type to double.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a for loop instead.
However, the reason the your code didn't work, is because you are trying to set a type of `double` to a `IEnumerable<Double>`. In C#, you would have to cast this (if you could) or just create the variable `average` as the same type the `Take()` and `Reverse<>` method return. For example, if you had a method that returned a `bool`, you can't set `int i` equal to that method because you would be setting two different types to eachother. You can also do what Dmitry had commented as this would just return the type of double, `double lastThree= list.Reverse<Double>().Take(3).Average();`

```
public static double last3YearsInInches(List<Double> list)
{
        Double average = 0.0;
        if (list.Count < 3)
        {
            return 100;
        }
        else
        {
            //using a for loop instead of .take() to get the last three elements
            for(int i = list.Count - 3; i < list.Count; i++) 
            {
                average += list[i];
            }
            return average / 3;
        }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
list.Reverse<Double>().Take(3);
```

returns an object: List that has 3 items inside.

Correct, "else" statement:

```
else
        {
           List<Double> lastThree= list.Reverse<Double>().Take(3);
            double average = (lastThree[0]+lastThree[1]+lastThree[2]) / 3;
            return average; 
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).